# Deserialize an xml file or parse using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Simplified XML file I need to decode:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:deliverylistResponse xmlns:ns2="http://tdriverap3.wsbeans.iseries/">
         <return>
            <COUNT>3</COUNT>
            <DELIVERIES>
               <ADD1>1300 address 1</ADD1>
               <CITY>NICE CITY</CITY>
               <ZIP>85705</ZIP>
            </DELIVERIES>
            <DELIVERIES>
               <ADD1>40 S PINAL PKWY AVE</ADD1>
               <CITY>FLORENCE</CITY>
               <ZIP>85132</ZIP>
            </DELIVERIES>
            <DELIVERIES>
               <ADD1>1825 EAST MAIN</ADD1>
               <CITY>CHANDLER</CITY>
               <ZIP>85286</ZIP>
            </DELIVERIES>
            <ERRORCODE/>
            <RUNDATE>09/26/2018</RUNDATE>
         </return>
      </ns2:deliverylistResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using the following to try and decode each of the individual addresses in the code.

I cannot figure out how to access them.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"e:\test\X2.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> addresses = xelement.Elements();

        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(address);
            Console.WriteLine(address.Element("CITY").Value);

        }
```

The first writeline works (it outputs the entire XML tree), the second says "System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) returned null" - I have tried using DELIVERIES, COUNT, Body etc...

Obviously I am not telling it correctly how to traverse the structure, but I do not know how to go any further with it..

UPDATE: Thanks to some help I have figured out how to do it using Linq.
I would still like to be able to deserialize it if anybody has a pointer.
I followed several tutorials, but the multiple levels of this XML seems to be throwing me off.

I have created a class to hold the data but that is as far as my success with that path has gone.

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: Take a look [at some examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml)

Comment: I have read that page and about a dozen others.
I still cannot figure out how to tell it to step through the file and pull the data out for each DELIVERIES node (?), element(?)
In my code above the addresses has only one entry in the results view.

Comment: [This is very similar to what you want to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-descendants-with-a-specific-element-name#example-1). Replace "t" with "DELIVERIES" and don't project a string selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Crowcoder -- this is what I wound up with, which will work.
The real XML file however does have about 60 fields so this is not as good as using a deserialize routine but I can at least move forward with the project.

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"e:\test\x2.xml");

            IEnumerable<XElement> textSegs =
                 from seg in xelement.Descendants("DELIVERIES")
                  select seg;

            foreach (var address in textSegs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(address.Element("ADD1").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(address.Element("CITY").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(address.Element("ZIP").Value);

            }


            Console.ReadKey();
```